# Can I compare int with size_t directly in C?

Tags: c, casting, integer, size-t

Can I compare an `int` and a `size_t` variable like this:

```
int i = 1;
size_t y = 2;
if (i == y) {
    // Do something
}
```

Or do I have to type cast one of them?

Comment: Do you really need to compare an `int` to a `size_t`? Generally you shouldn't, and you may be wrongly converting an `int` to `size_t` or viceversa somewhere.

Comment: just for the sake of knowledge :)

Comment: The "obvious" case for comparing an int and a size_t is `snprintf()`.

Comment: You may want to bounds check an int, or unsigned int, vector index.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It's safe provided the `int` is zero or positive. If it's negative, and `size_t` is of equal or higher rank than `int`, then the `int` will be converted to `size_t` and so its negative value will instead become a positive value. This new positive value is then compared to the `size_t` value, which may (in a staggeringly unlikely coincidence) give a false positive. To be truly safe (and perhaps overcautious) check that the `int` is nonnegative first:

```
/* given int i; size_t s; */
if (i>=0 && i == s)
```

and to suppress compiler warnings:

```
if (i>=0 && (size_t)i == s)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to compare an int type to `size_t` (or any other library type), you are doing a risky comparison because `int` is signed and `size_t` is unsigned, so one of them will be implicitly converted depending on your compiler/platform.  The best thing to do, is to rewrite your `int i` as:

```
decltype(y.size()) i = 1;
```

This assigns your `i` as the safe type you're trying to compare, and I think it's good practice.  This solution is useful in all types of iterators as well.  You generally don't want to trust the compiler to cast for you, you can, but it's risky, and an unnecessary risk.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is going to be some sort of integer type (although possibly unsigned, so it might generate a warning) so the appropriate casting should be done for you automatically.

As others have already said, you may want to revisit whatever calculation is producing the `int` and see if you can do it in `size_t` in the first place if you're computing a required size for something.

Comment: `size_t` *must* be unsigned.

Comment: Actually unsigned types create more problems than they solve (when used for sizes).  A better advice would be to run away from unsigned as a quantity as soon as possible (casting to `int`). You can have problems around `INT_MAX` values, but with unsigned you can have problems around zero and that is a lot more common in programming.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to compare a `size_t` value with an `int` value, the `int` value will be implicitly converted to `unsigned` type.

Some compilers will issue a warning when you mix `signed` and `unsigned` types in comparisons. In that case you can explicitly convert the `signed` value to an appropriate `unsigned` type to suppress the warning.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to just cover up compiler warnings like this, IMO.  There are better alternatives (e.g. using one of `size_t` or `int` instead of both in the first place).

Comment: That comparison may cause an `undefined_behaviour` when compiler optimisation is enabled.