# Comparing negative numbers in C

Tags: c

I am having a problem with a program I wrote. The program is going into a if statement whereas it should not. 
I have two variables:

```
size_t len = 5;
int    tmp = -1;
```

When I do :

```
if (tmp > len)
    ft_putstr("this is crazy");
```

I prints out "this is crazy whereas -1 is smaller than 5 to me !
Ok, ok. So I looked on my favorite website and saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642010/comparing-int-with-size-t).

When trying:

```
printf("%zu", tmp)
```

I see a big positive number. Ok ! This might be the reason why my program goes into the if condition above, but how can I make it not to go inside the if condition ??? thanks

Comment: It's because `size_t` is an unsigned integer type, so when comparing a signed integer type to it, an unsigned comparison is performed.

Comment: Try `if (tmp > 0 && tmp > len)`

Comment: `printf("%zu", tmp);` causes undefined behaviour. With `printf` it's up to you to use the right format specifier.

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you are trying to compare something that is unsigned with something that is signed. This means that there's an implicit conversion involved before the actual conversion is done. In this case the signed is converted to unsigned (which is normally not what one would want - therefore many compilers have options to display warning when this is done).

To do it more correct in a sloppy way you would write:

```
 if( (int)tmp > (int)len )
```

however this ignores the fact that `size_t` could have values that are too large for `int`. To be strict one would have to handle that the range of `int` combined with the range of `size_t` could be larger than any available type. This means that you would have to handle this in two cases, so you would use the fact that if `tmp<0` then `tmp<len` (mathematically, since `len>=0`). So for example mathematically `tmp<len` would be written as `tmp<0 || tmp<len`. And the opposite would be `tmp>=0 && tmp >= len`. You should therefore write:

```
 if( tmp >= 0 && tmp > len )
```

Note that then the conversion is not a problem, `tmp` could after the first check be converted to unsigned without change of value, different ranges of `int` and `size_t` are not a problem either as the smaller is converted to wider range before comparison.

The only problem left is that if you have enabled warnings about signed-unsigned comparison (to detect these kind of mistakes) it would still warn. To take care of that you would need to explicitely type cast it, but we know that conversion to unsigned doesn't change `tmp` once we checked that `tmp>=0`. So to avoid warnings you would write:

```
if( tmp >= 0 && (unsigned)tmp > len) )
```

the `(unsigned)` is because `tmp` is an `int`, you need to respect the type when converting to unsigned if `tmp` were of another type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between different variable type. variable types such as `int`, `unsigned`, `size_t` etc. has different behaviour and based on that you get the results.

If you truly want to compare two numbers, they all have to be on same level (variable type) else you get unexpected results.

Following will solve your problem.

```
if(tmp > (int)len)
    ft_putstr("this is crazy");
```

As @jblixr suggested (thanks for the comment), you may want to take care of `sizeof` these variable types and make sure that the values are not lost while converting the values from one data type to another data type.

Comment: Do you think it is a good solution ah? What happens if `len` is like `4294967295`? Then `len` will be treated like a negative number.

Comment: @jblixr If you are referring to sizeof `size_t` and `int`; NO.

Comment: How likely is it that a `size_t` value is larger than `INT_MAX`? Not very. This comparison is fine in the majority of cases.

Comment: @PerJohansson Under for example MS-dos that can happen when using huge memory model. With `INT_MAX` being 32767 and `size_t` being 32-bit you could be in for some trouble. Even on modern system under some 64-bit OSes you have `int` being 32-bit while `size_t` being 64-bit (and there are cases where you actually have `size_t` being larger than 2GiB). I'd say it's quite likely that `size_t` value is larger than `INT_MAX`.