# Multiple type specifiers in declaration list

Tags: c, for-loop, declaration, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //ask user for input
    string s = get_string();

    //make sure get_string() returned a string
    if(s != NULL)
    {
        //iterate over the characters one at a time
        for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
        {
            //print i'th character in s
            printf("%c\n", s[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //tell the user that their input is not a string
        printf("Sorry, no good\n");
    }

}
```

The compiler complained about this line:

```
for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
```

because I declared the integer `n` with `int` to define the type.

The program compiles just fine with:

```
for(int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
```

Why is `int` required/good form for `i`, but not for `n` in this example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing int with size\_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642010/comparing-int-with-size-t)

Comment: The statement `int i,n;` (whether in a for-loop or not) declares two variables (whereas `int i, int n;` is incorrect [also in either place]). Here, the OP also happens to be initialising them.

Comment: @Eimantas not at all.

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: @maraguida Ahh! thank you, I had no idea!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because this line:

```
int i = 0, n = strlen(s)
```

creates two integers called `i` and `n` and initialises them.

When you put:

```
int i = 0, int n = strlen(s)
```

You create an int called `i` and initialise it, and then you attempt to create another int called `int n` which doesn't make sense.

There's no reason to initialise `n` where it is - it shouldn't change, after all. Initialise it before the loop:

```
int n = strlen(s); 

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ...
```

Comment: That looks cleaner to me too, but the way the prof is doing it is the way I showed.

Comment: @phindex And that's fine, you can do it the way you had it in your question that worked.

Comment: @Steve I received great answers, and I upvoted them. Is there anything I need to do to 'close' my question or anything?

Comment: @phindex you can mark it as "answered"- https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. But otherwise, leave it as it is so others can find it if they're having the same issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Ah well, it happens. Somebody probably thought I was asking the OP to mark **my** answer.

Comment: No, I don't think so, you didn't coerce OP to mark any answer... just some jealous individuhal.

Answer (score 4):

The line `int i = 0, n = strlen(s)` is a declaration list. When you type the comma there, you say "give me another variable of the same type". The code is identical to something like `int x, y;`.

Note that it can be dangerous to declare several variables at the same line in some cases. There can be initialization misunderstandings and there could be misunderstandings about which variable that is a pointer, and which one that isn't. (`int* x, y` does *not* declare two pointers.)

Therefore it is good practice to *always* declare every variable on a line of its own. In addition, it is also good practice to keep for loops as clean and simple as possible. The best way to write that loop might therefore be this:

```
int n = strlen(s);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: As a side note, the most correct type to use when taking the length of an array, which is what we do in this case, is to use the integer type `size_t`. CS50 will not teach you this.

Comment: "Most correct type" aside, there's also the fact this is exactly what `strlen` returns. So it should be `size_t` if for no other reason than to avoid the implicit  conversion.

Comment: @Lundin Why *doesn't* CS50 teach size_t? Am I learning somewhere I shouldn't be?

Comment: @phindex Because it is apparently quite a crappy tutorial which has already gotten a bad reputation here on SO. I haven't read the complete course material though, so I could be wrong. The first chapters are however, definitely crap.

Answer (score 1):

When you used `int` first time, all comma separated variables are now int.

Meaning that 2 statements below are the same:

```
int a, b; //a = int, b = int
int a; int b; //a = int, b = int
```

Answer (score 1):

C allows you to declare multiple variables after the initial type declaration:

```
int x, y, z =0, whatever;
```

Adding an extra type declaration in the list is not allowed, even if it matches the original.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying this ;

```
int i = 0, int n =strlen(s);
```

It is not OK.
It is same that

```
int i = 0 , char s ;
```

You need to try those:

```
int i = 0, n=strlen(s);//or
/*-----------------*/
int n = strlen(s);
for(int i = 0;....)//or
/*-----------------*/
int i = 0;int n= strlen(s);//unnecessary but not wrong
```

And do not define irrelevant veriable at for(...),define before 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++){ /*...*/ }` is not valid C/C++ syntax.
`for(int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++){ /*...*/ }` is.
You'll only be able to do this is `i` and `n` are to have the same type, though. If you wanted them typed differently, you could do:

```
{ int i=0; long n=strlen(s); for(; i<n; i++) {  /*...*/ } }
```

which is both more flexible and more portable than the >=C99 `for` loops.

Comment: does not really add anything over existing answers

Answer (score -2):

The return type of the function `strlen` (as of the operator `sizeof`) is `size_t` that is an alias for an unsigned integer type usually `unsigned long`. So the type `int` is unable to accommodate all values of the type `size_t`.

So instead of the type `int` use the type `size_t`.

Moreover the shown by you for loop contains a syntax error.

Declarations are defined in the C Standard like

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration
```

So the declaration specifiers shall precede all declarators that is all declared identifiers in the list of identifiers.

So this declaration in the for loop

```
int i = 0, int n = strlen(s);
```

is incorrect because between the declarators `i` and `n` there is encountered declaration-specifier `int`.

Write

```
for( size_t i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(int i = 0, int n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
```

In fact there is no need to call the function `strlen`. The loop can be written without it.

```
    for( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        //print i'th character in s
        printf("%c\n", s[i]);
    }
```

Pay attention to that you should free the pointer `s`  declared like

```
string s = get_string();
```

at the program end. For example

```
free( s );
```

Comment: how the heck did this post get downwotes?

Comment: @sp2danny  Are these sanctions against Russia?:)