# Comparing size_t to -1

Tags: c, if-statement, type-conversion, size-t, equality-operator

*Note: it has been suggested that this question duplicates [Can I compare int with size_t directly in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642010/comparing-int-with-size-t), but the question here **specifically** asks about comparing size_t with a negative value.  For this reason, it should be re-opened.  (And besides, it has generated a lot of thoughtful discussion!)*

I'm staring at some library code (I am looking at you, [Microchip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_Technology)), declared to return a `size_t`:

```
size_t SYS_FS_FileWrite(SYS_FS_HANDLE handle, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

That is documented as returning -1 on an error.  But `size_t` is an unsigned value.  So, in theory and/or in practice, is the following allowed?

```
if (SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1) {
    report_errror();
}
```

Comment: When asking a question about a statement made in some document, give a URL or a bibliographic citation to that document and quote it, so that other people can examine it.

Comment: Assuming `SYS_FS_FileWrite()` returns `(size_t)-1` on error, the safest thing to do would be compare the return value to `(size_t)-1` rather than a plain old `-1` so that you do not have to worry about the value after conversion to a common type by the *usual arithmetic conversions*.

Comment: Converting `-1` to an unsigned integer type is a common and portable way to get the maximal value of that type.

Comment: @nielsen *Converting -1 to an unsigned integer type is a common and **portable** way ...*  Not if `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)`, then `-1` will not be converted at all.  `if (UINT8_MAX==-1)` isn't going to be true on all that many implementations...

Comment: @fearless_fool, "documented as returning -1 on an error" is poor documentation and simply wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle If it is not converted, then my comment does not apply since it only mentions the result of a conversion and nothing about when a conversion happens. My purpose in this context was to maybe explain why anyone would do the seemingly strange thing to return `-1` when return type is unsigned. Btw., it would be more readable to e.g. `#define ERROR_VALUE ((size_t)-1)` and use that as return value as well as for checking the returned result.

Comment: @nielsen Perhaps "Explicitly converting" would have been a better way to write it.

Comment: @IanAbbott That is a different statement. The result does not depend on whether or not the conversion is explicit. Then it could be "Explicitly or implicitly converting...". Anyway, I think the point has been made by now :-).

Comment: My preference would be to `#define ERROR_VALUE SIZE_MAX` as the error value -- that would avoid any ambiguity or portability issues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is impossible for a routine that returns a `size_t` to return −1, but it is perfectly fine for it to return the result of converting −1 to `size_t` (presuming the relevant environment does not need that value for any conflicting purpose). If the documentation states the latter, it is fine. If it states the former, the documentation is sloppily written and probably means the latter.

In a comparison of some `size_t` value `x` to `-1`, as in `x == -1`, the value −1 will be converted to the type `size_t` if the rank of `size_t` equals or exceeds the rank of `int`. This is the case in most C implementations and would be expected in an implementation that uses −1 converted to `size_t` as a return value. In a C implementation in which `size_t` had lower rank than `int`, `x` could be converted to `int` (depending on some specifics of the types). That would not change the value, and `x == -1` would always evaluate as false.

Per a request in the comments for a test of whether `SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1` is a safe test for `SYS_FS_FileWrite` returning −1 converted to `size_t` in light of the fact that the usual arithmetic conversions might not produce the desired results, a suitable test is `_Static_assert((size_t) -1 == -1, "size_t type is too narrow.");`. Also, the test could be written as `SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == (size_t) -1`.

Comment: Is it possible to formulate a "static_assert" to check if the rank of `size_t` equals or exceeds the rank of `int` ?

Comment: @nielsen `_Static_assert(SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX,"");` or the like.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Suppose `size_t` is `unsigned short` with `SIZE_MAX` = 65,535, and `INT_MAX` is 32,767. Then`SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX` is true (even given the usual arithmetic conversions), but `size_t` has lower rank than `int`. However, the `size_t` type and the “−1” value used in this case would not cause problems, so merely testing for rank is not necessarily what we want to do. It might be sufficient that `SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX` evaluates as true.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True that in that [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76035482/comparing-size-t-to-1#comment134101659_76035532) the ranking order is as described, yet IMO, [nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76035482/comparing-size-t-to-1#comment134100743_76035532)  true question goal, is not as stated  _check the rank_, but to determine, as you say, test for problems, which `SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX` should address.

Comment: Thanks both. Yes, my immediate question was to check for problems, but theoretically it is a bit funny that the C Standard states rules in terms of "rank" but does not offer any (obvious) way to compare ranks of two types. The Standard could have defined a `rank()` keyword the same way as e.g. `sizeof()`. It would not be necessary to specify the absolute "rank" values, only the order, i.e. `rank(type1) <= rank(type2)` if and only if `type1` is an integer type or of integer type with rank less than or equal to `type2`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: In one of those oh, this is obvious moments, an assertion that will test whether `SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1` is a safe test is of course `_Static_assert((size_t) -1 == -1, "size_t type is too narrow.");`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `_Static_assert((size_t) -1 == -1,...` is nicely to the point.   `SIZE_MAX >= INT_MAX` is useful in an `#if` to steer code as needed.

Comment: You can just have a constant `#define SYS_FS_FILE_WRITE_ERROR ((size_t)-1)` and `SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == SYS_FS_FILE_WRITE_ERROR` should work on all implementations without any asserts or `ifdef`s

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is allowed and it will work as intended.

When comparing the integer constant `-1` (which has type `int`) with a value of type `size_t`, the integer constant `-1` will be implicitly converted to `size_t`. Assuming that `size_t` has a width of 64 bits, it will be converted to the value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. The return value of the function `SYS_FS_FileWrite` will also have the value `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. Therefore, the comparison will work as desired.

As pointed out in one of the other answers, the ISO C standard does allow a compiler implementation to define the data type `size_t` in such a way that its [rank](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) is smaller than `int`. In the hypothetical case of this actually happening, the statements in my previous paragraph would not apply. The integer constant `-1` would retain its value and would not be converted to a positive value, so that the comparision would always evaluate to false. However, this is only a theoretical concern. In practice, you can rely on `size_t` having a rank that is equal to or higher than `int`.

It does not make much sense that the documentation states that the function will return `-1`. It would make more sense for the documentation to state that it will return `-1` converted to a `size_t`, i.e. that it will return the value `(size_t)-1`.

Comment: IMO, a clearer way to state it, for the case where `size_t` has a lower conversion rank than `int` (e.g. if it's `unsigned short`), is that `size_t` gets promoted to `int`, instead of the `-1` (which is implicitly an `int`) getting promoted + converted to an unsigned type to match `size_t` to make both sides of `==` match.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression of the if statement

```
if (SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1) {
```

there are used two operands of different types. The left operand of the equality operator has the type `size_t` and the right operand is the integer constant `-1` of the type `int`.

The compiler needs to determine the common type of the operands.

In this case there are used the so-called usual arithmetic conversions.

As the rank of the type `size_t` is not less than the rank of the type `int` (the typs `size_t` is usually an alias for the type `unsigned long` and in more rare cases for type `unsigned long long`) then the operand of the type `int` is converted to the type `size_t`.

So under the hood you have in fact

```
if (SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == ( size_t )-1) {
```

the same way as the returned integer constant `-1` from the function is converted to the type `size_t` according to the function return type

```
size_t SYS_FS_FileWrite(SYS_FS_HANDLE handle, const void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
    //...
    return ( size_t ) -1;
    //...
}
```

Thus the if statement may be interpreted like

```
if ( ( size_t )-1 == ( size_t )-1) {
```

provided that the function returns `-1`. Otherwise the left operand of the equation has some other value returned by the function and the expression evaluates to logical false (integer value `0`)

From the C Standard (6.5.9 Equality operators)

> 4 **If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed.** Values of complex types are equal if and
> only if both their real parts are equal and also their imaginary parts
> are equal. **Any two values of arithmetic types from different type
> domains are equal if and only if the results of their conversions to
> the (complex) result type determined by the usual arithmetic
> conversions are equal.**

Comment: "As the rank of the type `size_t` is not less than the rank of the type `int`" is commonly true, but not specified by C as true since `SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX` is possible.  In that case, `SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1` is never true.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Truly speaking I do not know where  the rank of size_t is less than the rank of int because  the C Standard recommends to use unsigned long type as the type size_t or in an exclusive case to use unsigned long long .

Comment: I've only once come across a 32-bit embedded machine with small memory that had `SIZE_MAX = 0xFFFF` and `INT_MAX == 0x7FFF_FFFF`.  Such machines are allowed by C, yet since they cause issues, as suggested with `SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX`, are relegated to "I don't care if it is possible, I am not writing code to support such unicorns" pile.

Answer (score 1):

> ...documented as returning -1

With standard `size_t`, impossible for a function returning `size_t` to return -1.  Such a function with `return -1;` instead returns `(size_t) -1` or `SIZE_MAX`.

> ... in theory and/or in practice, is the following allowed?

On select implementations where `SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX` is true, the following is **never** true, since `size_t` converts to an `int` before the compassion and all `size` are non-negative.

```
// Weak code
size_t SYS_FS_FileWrite(SYS_FS_HANDLE handle, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
if (SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == -1) {
  report_errror();
}
```

Commonly `SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX` is false though, so the `-1` converts to a `(size_t) -1` or `SIZE_MAX` and the compare is OK.

Better as:

```
if (SYS_FS_FileWrite(handle, buf, nbytes) == SIZE_MAX) {
  report_errror();
}
```

---

On review, this answer too close to  other answers, so many it wiki.